# Save image from url then get its location to set into a ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-external-storage

what i try to do here is to get an image from URL to later use that image for a menu (so I have to fill the ImageView with that image), so that image gonna stay there until a new update/upgrade for the menu.

I'm new with android and the examples to save an image does not show how to use it back. :(

Comment: What do you mean by location? The location of where the image has been saved to? Have you already looked at the [appropriate](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) section in the developer guide? The API offers you various means to get the used location of saved resources.

Comment: Gonna check that thank you.